# PyCharm shows duplicated code warnings from some checkpoint file that does not exist?

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

I'm getting some very annoying duplicated code warnings after I've edited one of my files in Jupyterlab and opened again in PyCharm.

There in some functions I get a duplicate code warning for the exact same function in some other file.

So if I have

```py
def foo(x):
    return x
```

in `file.py` I get a warning for

```py
def foo(x)
    returnx
```

for a `file-checkpoint.py` for pretty much every function and even some comments.

I don't have a file `file-checkpoint.py`

I've restarted this a few times and the warnings persist, it's so annoying I'm going nuts.

Could someone tell me how this happened?

Comment: Check you project -- look for `.ipynb_checkpoints` folder. Such `%ORIGINAL_NAME%-checkpoint.%ORIGINAL_EXT%` files should be there. Just right click on it in PyCharm Project View panel and use "Mark as Excluded" (or do it via `Settings/Preferences | Directories`)

Comment: Hi @LazyOne thanks. They are not. These are actually .py files, not notebooks, I just edited them in jupyter because I import the module in a notebook in a higher folder. Is that it? The names are completely different though

Comment: That is the folder where Jupyter Notebooks saves a most recent copy of modified (currently opened) `.ipynb` file when I'm using that notebook. If it's not saving `.py` files there for you .. then it must be some another folder. Please try this: 1) `Ctrl+Click` on such function call -- since PyCharm sees more than 1 definition it should ask where to go. Go through the route for `*checkpoint.py` one and see what the file path would be. 2) You may also try `Navigate | File...` and type the file name there (may need to include non-project files option). Post screenshots of what you see if nothing.

Comment: wait, I think I get it and also see where the error might come from, so when i open a .py file in jupter lab it also saves a *checkpoint.py file of that file even though it's not a notebook?